# how to show inherit groupbox in C#

Tags: c#

My english isn't very good.

Hi, I have class where I inherit from GroupBox and I want to use polymorphism and I see in debugger that all is corrent but after compilation I see nothing... 
Here is screenshot like it is and how it should be.

```
grid = new Grid.KierownikGrid();
SetGrid();

private void SetGrid()
{
    grid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 0);
    grid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10,10);
    grid.TabIndex = 10;
    grid.TabStop = false;
    grid.Text = "";
}

public class KierownikGrid : GroupBox
{
    RadioButton addUsers;
    RadioButton deleteUsers;
    RadioButton troubles;

    public KierownikGrid()
        :base()
    {
        Inicjacja();
    }

    protected void Inicjacja()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(addUsers = new RadioButton());
        this.Controls.Add(deleteUsers = new RadioButton());
        this.Controls.Add(troubles = new RadioButton());

        this.addUsers.AutoSize = true;
        this.addUsers.Checked = true;
        this.addUsers.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 10);
        this.addUsers.TabIndex = 0;
        this.addUsers.TabStop = true;
        this.addUsers.Text = "Dodaj użytkownika";
        this.addUsers.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

        this.deleteUsers.AutoSize = true;
        this.deleteUsers.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(125, 10);
        this.deleteUsers.TabIndex = 1;
        this.deleteUsers.Text = "Usuń użytkownika";
        this.deleteUsers.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

        this.troubles.AutoSize = true;
        this.troubles.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 10);
        this.troubles.TabIndex = 2;
        this.troubles.Text = "Problemy";
        this.troubles.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFu4t.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqeim.png

Comment: did you add the grid as a child of something?

Comment: no, I didn't. Should I do that??

Comment: well how would it know where to show it? how does it know which form to put it on? you added the controls to the grid, but you didnt think to add the grid as a control on the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BugFinder already mentioned you have to add your control to a form.

There is a [tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319266/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-windows-forms-at-run-time-by-using-visual-c) for that.

```
    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        //Controls.
        private TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
        private Button btnAdd = new Button();
        private ListBox lstBox = new ListBox();
        private CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
        private Label lblCount = new Label();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
           //Add controls to the form.
           this.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
           this.Controls.Add(txtBox);
           this.Controls.Add(lstBox);
           this.Controls.Add(chkBox);
           this.Controls.Add(lblCount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: links can die, so please post a relevant code sample.